# UISwitch, if/else statement to filter TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiswitch

So I'm creating a Settings view (SettingsViewController) for my app, and the view contains 5 switches. I'm looking to accomplish the following:

**if switch is on, filter TableView to only display items that contain 'Arthritis'. if switch is off, display all items.**

Note: the TableView is located on another view (ViewController).

Now even though I've imported ViewController.h onto my SettingsViewController.m file, it's telling me that StrainTableView is unidentified. Any idea as to why? See code below (you can ignore the PickerView references).

**SettingsViewController.h**

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController {


IBOutlet UISwitch *ArthritisSwitch;
IBOutlet UIView *CancerSwitch;
IBOutlet UISwitch *HIVSwitch;
IBOutlet UISwitch *InsomSwitch;
IBOutlet UISwitch *MigSwitch;
IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel;

       NSArray *arthritisResults;
     NSArray *Strains;
}


-(IBAction)switchtheswitch:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arthritisResults;


@end
```

**SettingsViewController.m**

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"



@interface SettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController
@synthesize arthritisResults;


-(IBAction)switchtheswitch:(id)sender; {

    if (ArthritisSwitch.on) {


        NSPredicate *ailmentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title ==[c] 'Arthritis'"];

        arthritisResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:ailmentPredicate];


        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...

        [StrainTableView setSearchResults: [arthritisResults copy]];

        NSLog(@"%@", arthritisResults);
    }

    else {

          [Strains count];


    }
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "PickerViewController.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <PickerViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{

    NSArray *searchResults;
    // NSArray *Strains;
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
    NSArray *Strains;


}


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * favoritesArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *searchResults;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *StrainTableView;


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just importing a class does not allow you to use a property from that class. You need to get an instance of the ViewController class (let's call it vc for example), and then use it like so:

```
[vc.StrainTableView setSearchResults: [arthritisResults copy]];
```

How you make that instance of ViewController depends on the structure of your app. You probably don't just want to alloc init one, but get a reference to one that you already have.

BTW, your code would be easier to read and understand if you conform to the naming convention of using lowercase letters to start properties and methods (and capitals for classes).

Comment: Ok, so pardon my newbie response (lol), but how can I create an instance of viewcontroller class (or rather, create a reference to an existing one in SettingsViewController)?

Comment: The way you create an instance of the viewController class is you import the header, which you did. After that, in your .h file, you create a variable of they type represented by the view controller so like Nameofyourviewcontroller *instanceoftheviewcontroller;

Comment: @user784044, no, that does not create an instance of the view controller, it just creates a property that's typed to that view controller's class.

Comment: @BrittanyL, As I said in my answer, it depends on the structure of your app. How are you getting SettingsViewController and ViewController on screen? Which comes first? Are you using a storyboard? A navigation controller? You need to provide some detail on what you're doing.

Comment: @rdelmar from what I understand, and from what I have been doing in my apps, instantiating the view controller is the same as creating an instance variable of the view controller.  I'm sorry if I was unclear in my comment.  I didn't mean to make it sound as if I was saying to generate properties of the view controller.

Comment: @user784044, No, instantiating a view controller is not the same as creating an instance variable of the view controller -- If you log that instance variable it will be null . You need to do an alloc init, or otherwise create the new instance (for instance with self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"whatever").

Comment: Oh my apologies.  @rdelmar

Comment: @rdelmar Amazing. ViewController *StrainTableView; worked magic :) Thank you!